# Game Center not in capabilities library; how can I enable Game Center in my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, game-center

The very first step in the article [Enabling and Configuring Game Center](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/enabling_and_configuring_game_center) is to add the "Game Center" capability from the capabilities library. However, the capability "Game Center" is not in my capabilities library:

[image: my capabilities library]

I'm running Xcode 14.0 on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you have already enabled it. Look for your `entitlements` file and see.

[image]

If you don't see that, maybe the problem is that you're not a paid developer member; some entitlements will be unavailable to you (your list appears remarkably short).

Comment: Yup, the problem was that I was not a paid developer; joining the Developer program fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice, it's great that you worked this out.